# Javascript: convert <textarea> with markdown + latex formatting to html

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathjax, showdown

Essentially I'm trying to create an input area that allows the user to enter markdown as well as latex (using $..$ and $$..$$), very similar to what you can do in an R notebook. As the user enters text, I'd like to convert it into a html format (and display it in another div).

I was able to get the markdown working well with showdown from reading other questions as shown below

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.9.0/showdown.min.js"></script>`

```
document.getElementById('markdown-input').addEventListener('change',function(){
    var markdownConverter = new showdown.Converter();
    markdownText = document.getElementById('markdown-input').value;

    var html = markdownConverter.makeHtml(markdownText);
    document.getElementById('markdown-container').innerHTML = html;
});
```

The trouble I am having is how to get the Latex working. I have been reading up on Mathjax, but have been having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to get that working alongside this especially with version 3. I have currently got the following scripts to use Mathjax, but unsure how to get these to work with the code above.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\(","\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ]}});
  </script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
```

Any advice on how to get this working would be really appreciated.

Comment: Some Markdown in-browser tools (like "marked") allow for code escapes, so that you can (for example) hijack one of the image or link syntax alternatives for your MathJax code. I would do it that way because you're going to have the problem of deciding which processor should run first. If you do it with Markdown syntax hacks, the the Markdown process can leave `<div>` elements (or whatever) to be filled in when the HTTP request for MathJax processing finish. I don't think this is a simple problem, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of research, I've managed to get it working.

I found my way to [Configuring MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html#configuring-mathjax), to modify my existing reference to the MathJax js files:

```
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]}
};
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
```

Then it was a simple code from another section of the documentation [Dynamic Content](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html), which calculates all the latex within the page synchronously, which I typed after parsing the markdown:
`MathJax.typeset();`

I'm not sure if there is a way to optimise this to only run for a particular element and its children, but it is currently working exactly how I need it to.